# Sine regression PHP

Tags: php, math, regression, trigonometry

I have a one-dimensional data set in PHP, to be precise, an array with linearly increasing indices (to represent the values on the x-axis, the delta being 1) and corresponding values (representing the values on the y-axis). My question is: how can I make a sinusoidal regression for such a data set? I have found linear, exponential and even logarithmic regression algorithms, but none for a sine curve.

The data set is formatted as such:

f(x) would be equal to `$array[$x]`, where x ∈ ℕ

Comment: x would be in terms of radians or degree? for example; sin(30) = will be 0.5?

Comment: it would rather be an arbitrary scale, since the data is also scaled on the y-axis. Usually, the values are within the bounds of 80 to 300, but the bounds vary. I therefore would like a regression method that takes the y-scale and y-offset into account.

Comment: $x = 85; f(x) = $array[$x]; so what would be the result for provided $x?

Comment: @cubuzoa: It shouldn't matter what units the angle is in since this will just be scaled by the frequency anyway. The regression algorithm should presumably return the frequency, phase, and amplitude of the sinusoid.

Comment: f(x) = a*sin(b*(x+c))+d; a, b, c and d all can vary, the function can be stretched on both axes and it can have an offset on both axes.

Comment: You should find by fourier series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Python implementation of a similar algorithm I came across the other day that might be helpful; it shouldn't be too difficult to translate it into PHP:

http://exnumerus.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/how-to-fit-sine-wave-example-in-python.html